# How to get public videos by location using youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hello i am new to Youtube api and looking for getting all the users public Youtube videos in Youtube by location using Youtube api .There are some existing apps like Geofeedia,COEverywhere, TrackinU which can get public posts of social networking sites by location . Is there is any way to get public Videos of an area in Youtube ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), using Search [list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) with location parameter:

> The location parameter, in conjunction with the locationRadius
>   parameter, defines a circular geographic area and also restricts a
>   search to videos that specify, in their metadata, a geographic
>   location that falls within that area. The parameter value is a string
>   that specifies latitude/longitude coordinates e.g.
>   (37.42307,-122.08427).
>
> The location parameter value identifies the point at the center of the
>   area. The locationRadius parameter specifies the maximum distance that
>   the location associated with a video can be from that point for the
>   video to still be included in the search results. The API returns an
>   error if your request specifies a value for the location parameter but
>   does not also specify a value for the locationRadius parameter.

Comment: Thanx for the reply ..what if i want all the public video of youtube with out location parameters