# How to get all public videos using youtube api without- Search: list?

Tags: youtube-api

Hello i am new to Youtube api and looking for getting all the users public Youtube videos in Youtube using Youtube api .There are some existing apps like Geofeedia,COEverywhere, TrackinU which can get public posts of social networking sites. Is there is any way to get public Videos of an area in Youtube ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get public videos by location using youtube api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240228/how-to-get-public-videos-by-location-using-youtube-api)

Comment: no i don't want it by location (i.e  by giving latitude and longitude) but i want all the videos that are  posted on youtube site using api .

Comment: Can you clarify this question? It sounds like you want to get all public videos from a user, but without using the API Search: list. But that's what Search:list can do - pass it the channel ID for the user and it returns those videos...

Comment: I want all the videos not specific to any channel or user .so that i can later filter using channel id or by user..Something same like Twitter Stream API which provides all the tweets of Twitter so far.